# In Lua what does an if statement with only one argument mean?

Tags: if-statement, lua, arguments

I've been taught to program in Java. Lua is new to me and I've tried to do my homework but am not sure what an if statement of the following nature means.

The code is as follows:

```
local function getMinHeight(self)
    local minHeight = 0
    for i=1, minimizedLines do
        local line = select(9+i, self:GetRegions())
        **if(line) then
            minHeight = minHeight + line:GetHeight() + 2.5
        end**
    end
    if(minHeight == 0) then
        minHeight = select(2, self:GetFont()) + 2.5
    end
    return minHeight
end
```

The if statement with the ** before and after is the part I'm not sure about. I don't know what the if statement is checking. If the line is not nil? If the line exists? If what?

Answer (score 8):

In Lua, anything that's not `nil` or `false` evaluates to true in a conditional.

> If the line is not nil? If the line exists?

Yes to both, because they kinda mean the same thing.

The `select` function returns a specific argument from it's list of arguments. It's used primarily with `...`, but in this case it's being used to select the (i+9)th value returned by `self:GetRegions`. If there is no such value (for instance, if GetRegions only returns 5 values), then `select` returns nil.

`if(line)` is checking to see that it got a value back from `select`.

`if(line)` is being used as a shortcut for `if(line ~= nil)`, since nil evaluates to false in a conditional.

---

It's worth pointing out that this shortcut is not always appropriate. For instance, we can iterate all the values in a table like this:

```
key, val = next(lookup)
while key do
    print(key, val)
    key, val = next(lookup, key)
end
```

However, this will *fail* if one of the table's keys happens be `false`:

```
lookup = { 
    ["fred"] = "Fred Flinstone",
    [true] = "True",
    [false] = "False", 
}
```

So we have to explicitly check for `nil`:

```
key, val = next(lookup)
while key ~= nil do
    print(key, val)
    key, val = next(lookup, key)
end
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks a lot! Sorry again for saying argument instead of expression :D

Answer (score 2):

As Mud says, in lua anything other than `nil` and `false` is considered *truthy*. So the `if` above will pass as long as `line` is not `nil` or `false`.

That said, it worries me a bit the way you have phrased the question - "an if with only one argument".

First, it's not called "argument" - it's called *expression*. And in most languages *is always one*. In java, for example, you could do something like this:

```
bool found = false

...

if(found) {
  ...
}
```

`if`s only care about the final value of the expression; they don't care whether it's a single variable or a more complex construction.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the clarification. I'll be more accurate in my terminology in the future. Thanks for explaining this :D